# In my Git working tree why do I have files located in parent directories?

Tags: git

After reinstalling a few things (Node, Gulp..) I have files in my working tree that are located in parent directories with respect to my Git directory (I thought this was impossible). How to remove them (not physically) from Git altogether so Git never mentions them again?

Comment: `.gitignore` them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to remove them (not physically) from Git altogether so Git never mentions them again?

Generate `.gitignore` file and commit this file.

Here is a sample one:
https://www.gitignore.io/api/node

---

If you still want the file in the repository (with default values for example- its not what you described in your question) you should use the `assume-unchanged` flag on the tracked file.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index

#### --[no-]assume-unchanged

> When this flag is specified, the object names recorded for the paths are not updated.
>   Instead, this option sets/unsets the "assume unchanged" bit for the paths.
>
> When the "assume unchanged" bit is on, the user promises not to change the file and allows Git to assume that the working tree file matches what is recorded in the index. If you want to change the working tree file, you need to unset the bit to tell Git. This is sometimes helpful when working with a big project on a filesystem that has very slow lstat(2) system call (e.g. cifs).
>
> Git will fail (gracefully) in case it needs to modify this file in the index e.g. when merging in a commit; thus, in case the assumed-untracked file is changed upstream, you will need to handle the situation manually.

Comment: Thanks! But why do these files show up if they are not even in my Git folder but in some parent folder? It makes no sense to me.

Comment: Have you tested that you don't have .git folder in the parent directory?